# Match and remove first and second pattern within xml tags

Tags: sed, perl, xml, awk

How can I match and remove first and second pattern within xml tags using sed or awk?

Here is the example

```
<data>A78-1-1134-HI-1</data>
<data>T78-12-1346-AG-2</data>
<data>G78-4-2156-Ag-6</data>
<data>A78-10-1971-Hh-10</data>
```

This is the result I am trying to get:

```
<data>1134</data>
<data>1346</data>
<data>2156</data>
<data>1971</data
```

Can it be done in one line?
This is what I tried:

```
sed 's/^.*<data>[[:alnum:]]-[0-9]-/<data>/g;s/-[a-Z].*<\/data>$//g'
```

Or removing just a first pattern, when I use sed to print then it works:

```
sed -n 's/^.*<data>.*[[:alnum:]]-[0-9]-/<data>/p' file.xml | grep data
```

But then this command will not work:

```
sed 's/^.*<data>.*[[:alnum:]]-[0-9]-/<data>/' file.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few solutions:

1. If your file is really as simple as your example, you can do it with this `gawk` scriptlet. This assumes that your file consists of nothing but `data` entries as described in your question.

   ```
   gawk -F"-" '{print "<data>"$3"</data>"}' file.xml
   ```

   - `-F"-"` tells gawk to take `-` as the field separator, the script then prints the 3rd field.
2. For slightly more complex files that include lines you do not want, this will print only if the first `($1~/data/`) and last (`$NF~/data/`) fields contain `data`:

   ```
   gawk -F"-" '($1~/data/ && $NF~/data/){print "<data>"$3"</data>"}' file.xml
   ```
3. If your file can have many `<data>` entries and you only care about those that look like `A1-2B-C3-4D`:

   ```
   perl -ne '/(<data>).+?-.+?-(.+?)\-.+(<\/data>)/ && do{print "$1$2$3\n"}' file.xml
   ```

   `-ne` means apply this script to each line of the input file. In Perl (and many other tools), parentheses allow capturing regular expression matches. Here, I am capturing three patterns, the opening and closing tags (`$1` and `$3`) so I don't need to type them twice and the pattern we are looking for, `$2`.

   If you need to be more specific use this to only allow alphaneumeric characters in the first field and only digits in the others:

   ```
   perl -ne '/(<data>)[\w\d]+?-\d+?-(\d+?)\-.+(<\/data>)/ && do{print "$1$2$3\n"}' file.xml
   ```
4. This all assumes that your `<data>` and `</data>` tags are on the same line. If they are not, you can do something like this:

   ```
   perl -ne '
    $d++ if /<data>/; 
     /[\w\d]+?-\d+?-(\d+?)\-.+/ && do{
                print "<data>$1</data>\n" if $d>0
           }; 
    $d-- if /<\/data>/; 
   ' file.xml
   ```

   `$d` will be positive if we are within `<data></data>` tags. If we are and find a line that matches the regular expression, print.

---

UPDATE:

If you want to edit the file, not just print its contents but actually change the original file, use this:

```
perl -i -ne 's/(<data>).+?-.+?-(.+?)\-.+(<\/data>)/$1$2$3/; print' file.xml
```

Comment: I am getting a correct printed data by using perl command from your #3 solutions. How do I change the command so it will make the change to xml. <data> tags are not the only tags in xml, and there are space in the front of <data> tag.

Comment: @user2302372, see updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tools for the job. Don't parse XML with regular expressions, you will get it wrong. (That's (a) because it's theoretically impossible - XML is not a regular language, and (b) because your practical attempts might work on some XML documents but they will inevitably fail on others.)

With XSLT 2.0 this is a trivial transformation.

```
<xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '-')[3]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your repetitions are not specified correctly.  Also, I find it easier to use subexpressions to extract substrings.  I don't know your exact specifications for matching data, but this works for your sample data in the question (I *think* this is POSIX compliant):

```
sed 's/<data>[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}-[0-9]\{1,\}-\([0-9]\{1,\}\)-[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}-[0-9]\{1,\}/<data>\1/' file.xml
```

If you have GNU `sed` at your disposal, you can take advantage of it's extensions to Extended Regular Expressions for a simpler expression:

```
sed -r 's/^.*<data>[[:alnum:]]+-[0-9]+-([0-9]+)-[[:alnum:]]+-[0-9]+/<data>\1/' file.xml
```

Comment: I tried both commands but no success, nothing changes. This is rather a larger xml file and I just sampled out tags that need a change. Tags are in same line and there are spaces in front of <data> tag.